# Is there a natural , $1\leq t\leq n$ such that $(n,t)=1$ and $\frac{n}{(n,t-1)}=d$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $n$ an even number and $d$ be a divisor of  $\frac{n}{2}$. Is there a natural number  $1\leq t\leq n$ such that $(n,t)=1$ and  $\frac{n}{(n,t-1)}=d$?

$(n,t-1)$ is largest divisor of $n$ and $t-1$.

I think it is true, but can not prove it. Thanks.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: I think it is true, but can not prove it.